# Kraken Exchange Private Request

Tags: java

I want to try to use the Kraken API with Java. I know how I can get the public information, but how can I get the private ones with input parameters?

Little example:

```
aclass = asset class (optional):
    currency (default)
asset = base asset used to determine balance (default = ZUSD)
```

This is used to get the trade balance. But I don't know where I should put the parameters. I tried it with `https://api.kraken.com/0/private/TradeBalance?asset=ZEUR`

The result is `{"error":["EGeneral:Invalid arguments"]}`

How can I fix this?

Comment: Might want to remove the `api` tag, per the tag's description.

Comment: @user2366842 do you  mean remove the api from the url?

Comment: No, I mean edit the tag on the question itself, the tag says "Do Not Use"

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query private data, your requests must have two extra headers :

```
API-Key = API key
API-Sign = Message signature using HMAC-SHA512 of (URI path + SHA256(nonce + POST data)) and base64 decoded secret API key
```

You can get an real example of how the Api-Sign header is computed by looking at [this code on github](https://github.com/nyg/kraken-api-java/blob/master/src/main/java/edu/self/kraken/api/KrakenApi.java) (not mine)